# Tukey test in R positive estimate but non significant p value when analyzing Attrak Diff Questionnaire results

Tags: r, anova, tukey-hsd-test

I'm a Master's student analyzing the Attrak Diff questionnaire results from my user study. I do not have a background in statistics and I am struggling to interpret my results.

I ran one way repeated measures ANOVA and got a significant p value so I ran Tukey's to see which of the four questionnaire categories had significant difference.

I am now confused as two of the estimates are positive (which from my reading would mean significant difference?) but only one of those p values is then significant. I've come across wording such as 'detectable difference' when discussing the estimates, but this only further confused me. I couldn't find any question on here that exactly matched my case.

How do I accurately describe my results?

[image: tukey graph]

[image: R results]

This is my R code:

```
g <- glht(M,linfct=mcp('quality'='Tukey'))
summary(g)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to CV! No, the sign (positive or negative) of an estimate does not tell you anything about that estimate's significance. The "Estimate" column in your output represents differences in "value" between the combinations of factors listed in the first column. For instance, the first estimate means that the estimated difference between "Hedonic Quality Identification" and "Attractiveness" is -.31923 and that "value" is that much higher for "Attractiveness" than for "Hedonic Quality Identification". Generally, if the first condition in the comparison has higher value than the second, the estimate will be positive in sign, and if the second has higher value, then the sign will be negative.

Significance is another thing, it means whether we can reliably say the effect is different from zero. It is here represented by the p-value, and your function uses the conventional p-value cutoff point of 0.05, meaning that it flags an effect - a difference in "value" level between conditions - as significant if it has p-value lower than 0.05. P-value is based jointly on the magnitude of the estimate, magnitude of its error, sample size, and number of parameters you estimate in the model.

The procedure you use tests whether the difference (the estimate) is different from zero. Here, only the 4th and last contrast are significantly different from zero. As you can see, they are also largest in (absolute) magnitude.